# Multiple DB update query using Laravel 5

Tags: mysqli, laravel-5

I'm new in Laravel and I'm trying to update mysql table's multiple rows using one query. I need to update for example 100 rows like this:

```
 $q = \DB::table('exmaple')
                     ->where('exampleID', $array)
                     ->update(array('Viewed' => 1));
```

$array is array with ID-s.
I have try also to implode array to string, then execute query, but with no result. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
$q = \DB::table('example')
    ->whereIn('exampleID', $array)
    ->update(array('Viewed' => 1));
```

**whereIn()** accepts an array as a second parameter so all IDs in this array will be affected by the query.

Comment: @LusineMartirosyan please mark the question as resolved if this solved your problem.